# Beginner Javascript issue, (undefined mouse events) book's sample code not working?

Tags: javascript

I'm just starting off with JavaScript and programming. The sample code this JS book provided gives an undefined function in the console log  when I'm trying to use it from an external utils.js file. I'm not sure why its undefined. The path to the file is correct since my IDE found it. Any ideas why its not defined?
Here's the main page.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <script src="js/utils.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                mouse = utils.captureMouse(canvas);
                canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
                    console.log("x:" + mouse.x + ",y:" + mouse.y);
                }, false);
            };
        </script>
```

and here's the utils.js file:

```
utils.captureMouse = function(element) {
    var mouse = {
        x : 0,
        y : 0
    };
    element.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
        var x, y;
        if (event.pageX || event.pageY) {
            x = event.pageX;
            y = event.pageY;
        } else {
            x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        x -= element.offsetLeft;
        y -= element.offsetTop;
        mouse.x = x;
        mouse.y = y;
    }, false);
    return mouse;
};
```

and here's the console output.

```
file:C:/projects/js/utils.js
ReferenceError: utils is not defined utils.js:1
ReferenceError: utils is not defined main.html:14
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Need initialize `utils = {}` before assign utils.captureMouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define  `utils` before `utils.captureMouse` as  杨扬-momo said.

```
var utils = {};
utils.captureMouse = function(element) {
```

`utils` is not object until you defined it.

Comment: This worked thank you! Not sure why the book failed to mention defining utils.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error here: `utils.captureMouse`, because `utils` has not been defined, so you can't add properties to it. Right before that line add the line:

```
utils = utils || {};
```

which is a handy way to initialize a variable to an empty object if it isn't already. Nromally when you declare a variable you should also use the `var` keyword, but it seems like you want `utils` to be a global variable in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I got the same error when I used your suggestion right before I use utils.captureMouse = function (element). but it did work if I just used a straight up var for utils instead.